# Incrementar variável com loop for e while juntos

Tags: php

Olá

Eu estou utilizando um laço while em minha aplicação em PHP, mas eu preciso incrementar uma variável chamada ( $i ) mas parar de incrementar quando chegar a quantia de registros armazenados na variável ( $qtde ), como eu posso fazer isso sem utilizar laço FOR ?

```html
$sql = "SELECT id, fabricante, fornecedor, nome FROM produtos";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
  //Quantiade de produtos encontrados
  $qtde = $result->num_rows;
  //Incrementar esta variável
  $i = 0; 
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {

    $nome = $row['nome'];
    
    echo $nome;
    echo $i;

  }
}
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incremente `$i` dentro do laço, e altere a condição para verificar se chegou no máximo:

```
$qtde = $result->num_rows;
$i = 0; 
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() && $i < $qtde) {
  $nome = $row['nome'];
  $i++;
}
```